# Can DLCs be shared between accounts on Origin?

Tags: battlefield-4, origin

Two computers, two Origin accounts each has Battlefield 4 bought. But only I have a few DLCs(I do not have Premium nor does the other account).

Can DLCs be shared e.g the account that has no DLC can play the DLC that I have, without playing via my account?

Comment: Is there a possibility to sign in to both your friend and your account at the same time in the same instance of BF4?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, Battlefield 4 and its Content (Dlc's) sticks to your Origin Account. So if you start Battlelog you can Login with two diffrent Accounts when you open a second Browser, but if you join a Game it requires Origin to run with an Account logged in. And it is not possible to run Origin with a second Account.